# Flutter: Resize container depending on the aspect ratio of the network image

Tags: flutter, dart

#### My code

1. Have a container.
2. Download `Image` from network.
3. Fit the image as `BoxFit.fitWidth`.

#### What I want to do

Change the container aspect ratio to downloaded image (having the width constant. width constant as they need to appear aligned.)

#### The current code

```
...
...
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
    end: 10,
    // top: 10.h - scale * 25,
    bottom: widget.marginBottom,
  ),
  child: Container(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      color: widget.color,
    ),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Image.network(
          widget.listImages[index],
          fit: widget.boxFit,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
            return Image.asset(
              'images/place_holder.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The constraints of the external container make the width and height of the image different from your settings.
This involves Flutter layout principles, please see https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints.

UnconstrainedBox class,A widget that imposes no constraints on its child, allowing it to render at its "natural" size.

```
       UnconstrainedBox(
        child: Image.network(
          widget.listImages[index],
          width: 100,
          height: 300,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
            return Image.asset(
              'images/place_holder.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer much better.